# Path that maxima can read when called from php

Tags: php, maxima

I need to run maxima commands from php.
I have two linux servers with identical Centos and Maxima setups, but PHP versions are 7.18 and 7.19 respectively.
I have a directory containing the files "test.php" and "test_maxima.txt".
Permissions for "test_maxima.txt" are 0644 (but I tried 0777 as well).
The PHP include path on both servers is ".:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
".
When I run the command "maxima -b test_maxima.txt" directly from the command line on both servers it runs just fine.
The script "test.php" that contains, among other things the lines:

```
require 'test_maxima.txt'; // sanity test that PHP includes things in current path
print_r(`maxima -b test_maxima.txt`);
```

But when I call the script "test.php" from the browser, then on the server running PHP 7.18 the script runs the maxima script perfectly, but on the PHP 7.19 version, it displays the contents of "test_maxima.txt" as per the sanity test above, but this is followed by the output:

```
(%i1) batch("test_maxima.txt")
file_search1: test_maxima.txt not found in file_search_maxima.
```

Furthermore, if I run:

```
print_r(`maxima -b /var/www/html/test_maxima.txt`);
```

or if I add the current path with `file_search_maxima:append...` the output is just an asterisk (`*`).

Running:

```
print_r(`maxima -r 'debugmode(true);file_search_maxima();quit();'`)
```

yields identical results on both servers:

```
[/tmp/.maxima/$$$.{mac,mc,wxm}, 
/usr/share/maxima/5.41.0/share/$$$.{mac,mc,wxm}, /usr/share/maxima/5.41.0/shar\
e/{affine,algebra,algebra/charsets,algebra/solver,amatrix,bernstein,calculus,c\
obyla,cobyla/ex,cobyla/lisp,colnew,colnew/lisp,combinatorics,contrib,contrib/E\
ulix,contrib/Grobner,contrib/Zeilberger,contrib/alt-display,contrib/altsimp,co\
ntrib/binsplit,contrib/bitwise,contrib/boolsimp,contrib/coma,contrib/diffequat\
ions,contrib/diffequations/tests,contrib/elliptic_curves,contrib/elliptic_curv\
es/figures,contrib/format,contrib/fresnel,contrib/gentran,contrib/gentran/man,\
contrib/gentran/test,contrib/gf,contrib/integration,contrib/levin,contrib/lurk\
mathml,contrib/maxima-odesolve,contrib/maximaMathML,contrib/mcclim,contrib/nam\
espaces,contrib/noninteractive,contrib/odes,contrib/operatingsystem,contrib/pr\
im,contrib/rand,contrib/rkf45,contrib/sarag,contrib/smath,contrib/state,contri\
b/symplectic_ode,contrib/trigtools,contrib/unicodedata,contrib/unit,contrib/ve\
ctor3d,descriptive,diff_form,diff_form/tests,diffequations,distrib,draw,dynami\
cs,ezunits,finance,fourier_elim,fractals,graphs,hypergeometric,integequations,\
integer_sequence,integration,lapack,lapack/blas,lapack/lapack,lbfgs,linearalge\
bra,logic,lsquares,macro,matrix,minpack,minpack/lisp,misc,mnewton,multiadditiv\
e,numeric,numericalio,odepack,odepack/src,orthopoly,pdiff,physics,simplex,simp\
lex/Tests,simplification,solve_rat_ineq,solve_rec,sound,stats,stringproc,sym,t\
ensor,to_poly_solve,trigonometry,utils,vector,z_transform}/$$$.{mac,mc,wxm}, 
/usr/share/maxima/5.41.0/$$$.{mac,mc,wxm}]()
```

What could be the issue? Why can't maxima find the file in the current PHP working directory on one of the servers?

Comment: (1) What is content of test_maxima.txt? (2) The output of file_search_maxima shows that /var/www/html isn't among the directories which are searched, so it seems it must be necessary to append it to file_search_maxima. (3) If test_maxima.txt is not too big, maybe you can try `maxima --batch-string="expr1; expr2; expr3; ..."` where `expr1; expr2; expr3; ...` is the stuff in test_maxima.txt. (3) Note that file_search_maxima is a variable, not a function, so the `()` are unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you @RobertDodier. As I mentioned I did try to use file_search_maxima:append and I also tried to call the test file with a full path but the output was just an asterisk - I don't know what that means. Is that what maxima uses to denote a general error? The test file just contains some basic test code - prints maxima version number and whatnot. It runs fine directly from the command line. I don't actually need maxima_test to run - I'm just using it to debug the general problem so I can use it in a real context with lots of big scripts (part of moodle to be precise) on the second server.

Comment: My guess about the asterisk is that Maxima has run into a Lisp error, and the asterisk is the Lisp debugger prompt; just a guess. You mentioned that you have two servers, and on one Maxima runs correctly, and on the other, it doesn't. Perhaps you can take a look at what is the difference in the configuration between the two. My advice is to follow up with the Moodle project -- my guess is that people working with Moodle will have better ideas about solving problems like this one.

Comment: Another thought -- I think Maxima will only search for files named .mac or .lisp, so if your Maxima program is named .txt it might not be located. Maybe try renaming the file to test_maxima.mac and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you once again @RobertDodier - as I mentioned, the program does get called from the other server even though it is called .txt and the server configuration is completely identical except for PHP version 7.18 vs 7.19. I changed it to mac but it made no difference to the second server.